# How do you design an object that has a member which is a base class?

Tags: c++, oop

I have a question about object oriented design.

Lets say we have a Garage class which can contain Vehicle objects. These vehicles can be cars or boats. `Boat` and `Car` both extend `Vehicle`.

```
class Garage {
    Vehicle & v_;

    public Garage(Vehicle & v) : v_(v) {}
    public Vehicle getVehicle() { return v_; }
}
```

However, I want the garages to be very different depending on what vehicle it contains. So I thought about making two subclass called `BoatGarage` and `CarGarage` which both extend Garage.

Example:

```
class BoatGarage : public Garage {
    Boat & b_;
    public BoatGarage(Boat & b) : Garage(b), b_(b) {}
}
```

I have a couple questions.

1. By using a reference as a parameter in the constructor I'm making sure that I am not creating another copy of the boat right? Is it true that had the constructor been `BoatGarage(Boat b) : Garage(b), b_(b)`, I would have created 2 copies of the boat; one for BoatGarage and one for Garage?
2. Does it make sense to create 2 references to the same Vehicle? Like in this case I have both a Vehicle reference and a Boat reference to the same boat. Is this redundant?

---

EDIT: To clarify: The original problem I am facing is I just want a very generic way to handle garages and vehicles. I am just trying some stuff out to practice OOP with C++. I figure I wanted the Vehicles base class to be able to add vehicles in whenever I wanted. I created a Garage base class because perhaps I wanted to add some functions like "paint boat" or "fix_tire" to make modifications to the vehicle knowing its type

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? What should a vehicle do, what should a garage do? Why do you need the `Vehicle` base class, why do you need the `Garage` base class?

Comment: @Jefffrey - Yes thanks for commenting; I read something about the XY problem and may just have the wrong solution strategy. I have updated my post. However I still am curious about these OOP questions; perhaps in more complicated situations (or even this one) it may be useful to know how it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, what you write here is correct.
2. Actually, this is a bad design.  Having two references to the same object within a class means that code accessing the object via one reference could suddenly find that the object had changed, via the other; it adds the potential for ambiguity and confusion and as your program gets larger, any error that can arise out of such ambiguity probably will.

The class hierarchy should contain just one reference to the object.  To avoid slicing (to retain polymorphism) and to preserve encapsulation, return a `const` reference in the base class.

```
class Garage {
    Vehicle & v_;

    public Garage(Vehicle & v) : v_(v) {}
    public const Vehicle& getVehicle() const { return v_; }
           ^^^^^        ^              ^^^^^
}
```

Dispense with `b_` et al. in the subclasses, i.e.

```
class BoatGarage : public Garage {
    public BoatGarage(Boat & b) : Garage(b) {}
}
```

To allow the derived classes to manipulate the object, overload `getVehicle` with a protected non-const version:

```
protected Vehicle& getVehicle() { return v_; }  //This is in class Garage
```

and you should have everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

1. yes, that is right and good and proper.
2. How about this

```
class BoatGarage : public Garage {
    public BoatGarage(Boat & b) : Garage(b), b_(b) {}
    public Boat & getBoat() const { return (Boat &)_v; }
}
```

My proposed change to BoatGarage eliminates the extra reference to the boat.  Since you *know* that the `_v` is actually of type `Boat`, you can just cast it and avoid storing the second reference to `Boat`.

Also, note that I made `getBoat()` a `const` method.  You could do that to `getVechicle()` as well.

Comment: I don't know why StackOverflow refuses to syntax highlight that code.  I'm sorry.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks.  Is the problem that you can't have code following a list?  (Sorry, I can take this discussion to meta if necessary)

Comment: It looks like it, and I hadn't figured out the right way to fix that. But @jeffrey has the solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

With [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) you could use [std::shared_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/) (or some other smart pointer) for the member, then it could "be" (i.e. point to) the base class.

Notice that a subclass cannot have a field which is directly its superclass, otherwise it would intuitively need an infinite memory (its `sizeof` would be infinite). Of course the field could be a raw pointer, a reference, or a smart pointer.

Comment: What on **earth** does shared pointer have to do with any of this?  The OP is using **references** (which might well be to objects allocated on the *stack*) and is asking about what kind and how many references to hold in a particular class!  There is no heap management here at all, why are you talking about smart pointers!?